# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream

Tags: hadoop, oozie

While running oozie shell action we are getting error  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream`.
However we are getting this issue randomly.

Comment: Try oozie share lib as showed in blog here - http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie/

Comment: @squid This issue is happening randomly. If some jar is missing it should fail always right